# React-virtualized, List is Flickkering/lagging when scrolling

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am experiencing some problem when i scroll through my list.
Also notice the huge space at the bottom.
See video : https://vimeo.com/215349521

As far as i can see, im not making any huge mistakes.
But i do belive the problem is due to the CellMeasurer.

Chrome version: 58.0.3029.81

```
class PromotionList extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
        defaultHeight: 100,
        fixedWidth: true,
    });

    this.rowRenderer = this.rowRenderer.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchPromotionsIfNeeded();
}

rowRenderer({ index, parent }) {
    const { promotions } = this.props;
    const data = promotions.list[index];

    return (
      <CellMeasurer
        cache={this.cache}
        columnIndex={0}
        key={uuid.v1()}
        parent={parent}
        rowIndex={index}
      >
        <BlobItem
          key={uuid.v1()}
          type={BlobTypes.promotion}
          data={data}
          onClick={this.props.onItemClick}
          index={index}
        />
      </CellMeasurer>
    );
}


render() {
    const { promotions, previewSize } = this.props;

    return (
      <List
        height={300}
        width={previewSize.width}
        rowCount={promotions.list.length}
        deferredMeasurementCache={this.cache}
        rowHeight={this.cache.rowHeight}
        rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
        className="blobList"
      />
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Hmm. That flickering looks a bit like a browser bug at a glance. Maybe similar to the one shown in this comment? https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/453#issuecomment-288687484

Comment: @brianvaughn It doesnt look quiet the same, mine is bouncing all around even if I stop scrolling. But its not the CellMeasurer for shure, removed it and still the same. 

But i agree, it might be a browser bug, or something with the list component as suggested in the link you provided

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Found the solution after reading through the documentation.
Just needed to add the style in the "rowRender" method:

```
rowRenderer({ index, parent, style }) {
  const { promotions } = this.props;
  const data = promotions.list[index];

  return (
    <CellMeasurer
      cache={this.cache}
      columnIndex={0}
      key={uuid.v1()}
      parent={parent}
      rowIndex={index}
    >
      <BlobItem
        key={uuid.v1()}
        type={BlobTypes.promotion}
        data={data}
        onClick={this.props.onItemClick}
        index={index}
        style={style}
      />
    </CellMeasurer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer your own question!

Comment: magic. I think I get it based on the docs (switching static positioning to relative). if that's the reason, would you mind updating our answer / providing an explanation as to why this works?

Comment: This answer worked for me as well. I simply threw an enclosing <div> around it: 
<div style={style>
     <BlobItem .... /> 
</div> 

@azium I believe that this has to work this way because I'd imagine the virtualized library is doing funky absolute positioning things to push cells around the screen. Without the styling, stuff gets all higgledy-piggledy.

Comment: FWIW, this also works with `react-window`